# Does any set (with cardinality > 1) admit a topology that makes it a Polish space?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Does any set (with cardinality > 1) admit a topology that makes it a Polish space?

While I am curious about instances where empty or singleton sets are violate the above, I am most interested in infinite sets.

Also, I'd appreciate it if an answer would include some general background/reasoning/explanation as opposed to just an example alone.

---

The main question is part of a general query that I have: Given a set $X$ and a topological property $P$ (compact, separable, metrizable, etc.), can one always define a topology on $X$ that has the property $P$?

Comment: To be finite is a topological property, because every homeomorphism is a bijection. More generally the cardinality of a topological space is a topological invariant.

Comment: The title of your question and the question itself are not in sync... which is not easing possible answers. And as you say, the question is probably too vague. At least, Wikipedia on [Polish spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space) states *In particular, every uncountable Polish space has the cardinality of the continuum.*

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I reformatted the question, does that help?

I take it from the wikipedia quote that there are no Polish spaces with cardinality greater than $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let us discuss the case where $X$ is countable. Give $X$ the discrete metric (the distance between a point and itself is 0, the distance between any two distinct points is $1$), which induces the discrete topology on $X$. Now, note that any discrete metric space is complete: the only Cauchy sequences are those that are eventually constant (choose $\varepsilon < 1$), hence they converge. Furthermore, since $X$ is countable, $X$ is a countable dense subset of itself. So, $X$ is Polish.

The comment by mathcounterexamples.net addresses the case where $X$ is uncountable and has cardinality $\neq \mathfrak{c}$: since every uncountable Polish space has cardinality $\mathfrak{c},$ any uncountable set $X$ with cardinality not equal to $\mathfrak{c}$ cannot be given a topology that makes it a Polish space.

So, all that remains is the case where $X$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}.$ Clearly, there exists a bijection $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}.$ We can define a topology on $X$ as follows: a subset $S \subseteq X$ is open if and only if $S = f^{-1}(U)$ for some open $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. (You should check that this actually does define a topology.) Furthermore, under this topology, $f$ automatically becomes a homeomorphism from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}.$ So, $X$ with this topology is homeomorphic to the Polish space $\mathbb{R}$, hence itself is Polish.

---

Now, to address some other parts of your general question:

- Given a set $X$, one can always give $X$ a topology that makes it compact: give it the indiscrete topology, where the only open sets are $\emptyset$ and $X$ itself. Since there are only finitely many open sets, any open cover is finite, hence a finite subcover of itself.
- Given a set $X$, one can always give $X$ a topology that makes it separable: once again, give it the indiscrete topology. Any singleton $\{x\} \subseteq X$ is contained in every nonempty open set of $X$ (there is only $X$ itself), hence every singleton $\{x\}$ is a countable dense subset of $X$.
- Given a set $X$, one can always give $X$ a topology that makes it metrizable: give it the discrete topology, where every subset of $X$ is open. Note that the discrete metric on $X$ defined above (the distance between a point and itself is 0, the distance between any two distinct points is $1$) induces the discrete topology, hence the $X$ with the discrete topology is metrizable.

Comment: Another option for the countable case is to make it homeomorphic to a convergent sequence like $\{0\} \cup \{\frac1n\mid n=1,2,\ldots\}$ or another compact ordinal like $\omega+\omega+1$ etc. In all cases we can make it compact metrisable (e.g. $2^\omega$ in the continuum case), so Polish a fortiori.